# Как сделать шорт код по поддоменам в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть несколько поддоменов 5-10, нужно вывести на каждом поддомене свой текст.

Как сделал я

```
$robots = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if ($robots == '1.doman.ru')
{
  function one_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     return '<div>' . $content . '</div>';
  }
  function two_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     return '<div style="display:none;">' . $content . '</div>';
  }
  function tree_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     return '<div style="display:none;">' . $content . '</div>';
  }
}
elseif ($robots == '2.doman.ru')
{
  function two_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     return '<div>' . $content . '</div>';
  }
  function one_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     return '<div style="display:none;">' . $content . '</div>';
  }
  function tree_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     return '<div style="display:none;">' . $content . '</div>';
  }
}
elseif ($robots == '3.doman.ru')
{
  function tree_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     return '<div>' . $content . '</div>';
  }
  function two_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     return '<div style="display:none;">' . $content . '</div>';
  }
  function one_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     return '<div style="display:none;">' . $content . '</div>';
  }
}

add_shortcode( 'one_shortcode', 'one_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'two_shortcode', 'two_shortcode' );
add_shortcode( 'tree_shortcode', 'tree_shortcode' );
```

Все работает, в примере я указал 3 домена, а по факты их около 10 и что-то мне подсказывает, что это неправильный подход и все делаеться как-то проще, вопрос, как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал один шорткод, в который передавал домен ($robots), и всю логику описал бы в шорткоде.

Передать параметр в шорткод:

```
[one_shortcode customparam='1.doman.ru']
```

Обрабатывать:

```
add_shortcode('one_shortcode', function ($atts) {

$domain = $atts['customparam'];

//тут описываем логику

return $domain;
});
```